# PNP vs NPN input to LM7805 VR

Tags: voltage-regulator

Can I use the output of an NPN proximity switch as the input to an LM7805 (positive input) voltage regulator? I'm a little confused on PNP vs NPN, but I'm reading as fast as I can. Also I see that they make an LM79xx series of VR's that, I think, accept a negative voltage as the input, would this negative voltage come from an NPN style device?
Thanks, Jim G.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use a regulator with an enable input?

Answer (score 1):

You want a PNP type. That type sources current.

If you need to use an existing NPN type you can add a high side switch, but at that point you'd perhaps be be better off using a regulator with an enable input as @Ignatio suggests.

Here is one way to do the former:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHEDXw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The proper choice of R1/R2/Q2 depends on the current you intend to draw from U1.